# UITableView on UIScrollView - didSelectRowAt not called on tap (gesture recognizer traps tap)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, didselectrowatindexpath, gestures

I have a UIScrollView on which I place some text fields and a tableView.

This is not a table delegate issue.  I can get didSelectRowAt if I click and drag on a row.  Just the simple row tap does not get through.

I do not show the table implementation below because it generally works and I think it is the gesture bit that is causing the problem.

I have added a gesture recognizer to the UIScrollView so that if you tap on the view background you will end the editing of the current field. This works to dismiss editing and keyboard, but for a **UITableView** I do not get the didSelectRowAt when I tap on a row. I have to press the row and drag horizontally in order to get the didSelectRowAt method call.

Is there a way to forward the tap gesture to the UITableView?  Or is it just a bad idea to use the gesture recognizer on the UIScrollView if I have a table on that view?  A button on that same view **will** get the tap and process the button event.  Not sure why the table **will not** get the tap. The table will scroll also properly, but does not see the row tap.

The main UIView Class Methods

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1.0)  // was .97


        // Container
        setupScrollView()

        registerKeyboardNotifications()
        addGestureRecognizer()

    }

    func setupScrollView() {

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin

        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }


     func addGestureRecognizer() {
        // When tap on the container -- end editing on current field
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(tapDidTouch(sender: )))
        self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
     }

     @objc func tapDidTouch(sender: Any) {  // this method eats UITableView clicks
        self.view.endEditing(true)
     }
```

The extension for handling keyboard

```
     extension TestView {
          func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
          let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
          notificationCenter.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notif:)),name: .UIKeyboardWillShow,object: nil)
          notificationCenter.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notif:)),name: .UIKeyboardWillHide,object: nil)
          notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notif:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
      }

      @objc func keyboardWillShow(notif: Notification) {
            guard let frame = notif.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return}
     scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0,
                                           left: 0.0,
                                           bottom: frame.height,
                                           right: 0.0)
      }

      @objc func keyboardWillHide(notif: Notification) {
          scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets()
      }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `keyboardDismissMode` property of the scroll view instead of using your own gesture recognizer?

Comment: is the tableview a subview of your scrollview?

Comment: I am not using the gesture recognizer to scroll. I am trying to use it to dismiss editing so when the user taps out of a view being edited so the editing will stop.    Yes, the TableView is a subview of then scroll view. The table itself scrolls up and down with the scrollview.  The table itself does also scroll when scroll on the table.